# Xcode App Store Preview, can App Store Preview Video have watermark on the video?

Tags: app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I am currently preparing my app on App Store Connect. I have made the preview video for my app, but the resolutions don't match, so I used a website to change the resolution, however it comes with a watermark on the bottom right hand corner. Will Apple allow this? Or will they reject if they see a watermark?
Thanks

Comment: Only Apple knows the answer.

Comment: Having any watermarks is a bad practice at all. Use free apps for changing resolution, like apple's iMovie for MacOS.

Comment: Oh ok, I did make it on iMovie but the 6.5 inch resolution and 5.5 inch resolution are different scales, and IMovie doesn't resize it. there's also a black space on the 6.5 inch video which I don't know is a good or bad thing?